# Excel: How to find six different combinations of words in string?

Tags: excel-formula

I have been working for several days on this and have researched everything looking for this answer. I'd appreciate any help you can give.

In Excel I am searching a string of text in column A:

Bought 1 HD Sep 3 2021 325.0 Call @ 2.75

I am detecting the first word (in this case "Bought") and detecting the last word before "@" symbol (in this case "Call").

I am then detecting the price following the "@" symbol (in this case "2.75"). This number will go into column B (header "Open") or column C (header "Close") depending on the combination of words found:

```
Sold/Put=Close
Sold/Call=Open
Bought/Put=Open
Bought/Call=Close
Sold (by itself)=Open
Sold (by itself)=Close.
```

---

Bought 1 HD Sep 3 2021 325.0 Call @ 2.75

The combination found in the above string is:  "Bought Call". Therefore the number at the end ("2.75"), goes into "Open" column.

---

Here's another example:

Sold 4 AI Sep 17 2021 50.0 Put @ 1.5

The combination found in the above string is: "Sold Put". Therefore the number at the end ("1.5") goes into "Close" column.

---

I am currently using this formula to determine if the string contains "Sold" and "Call" and get the desired number and it does work:

```
=IF(AND(
ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Sold","Call"},A10))),
TRIM(MID(A10,SEARCH("@",A10)+LEN("@"),255)),"  ")
```

But, I don't know how to search for all the other possible combinations.

The point behind this is to be able to paste the transaction from the broker and have most of the entry process automated. I'm sure many will benefit from this as I've not found anything like this.

I'd appreciate any help and if possible, an explanation of the formula so I can better learn.

Thanks!

Comment: I noticed someone is indicating that my question is unclear or not useful, please let me know how I can make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: So you are trying to extract the premium per contract, and the buy/sell and put/call determines which column you put it in?

Comment: I think its a great Q - sorry I couldn't give it another upvote...

Comment: @Euler'sDisgracedStepchild: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea, but would just extend the `IF` statement.

Something like the below might work for you:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Call", $A1)),

IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Bought","Sold"}, $A1)),
NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT($A1, LEN($A1)-SEARCH("@", $A1))),""),

IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"!!!","!!!","Bought","Sold"}, $A1)),
NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT($A1, LEN($A1)-SEARCH("@", $A1))),""))
```

Just enter in column B and drag down; columns B through E should fill as needed.

For example:

[image]

Note that the search for "!!!" is just random characters, it can be anything that you don't think has a good chance of appearing in the string.

Comment: Thanks EDS. I tried this, but it didn't seem to work. It simply returned "FALSE" even when the criteria matched. Also, I only have 2 columns I am sorting the price out into. I am using Excel Professional Plus 2019. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @J. Feeble hmm it could be a version issue as I am using 365, but not sure. You say you are sorting into just 2 columns: is the criteria puts and calls, or buys and sells?

Comment: Both. I'm trying to track both option purchases and sells and stock purchases and sells and sort the price into either "Open" or "Close" columns. Here are the 6 possible categories and the columns the price should go in: Sold/Put=Close, Sold/Call=Open, Bought/Put=Open, Sold/Call=Close, Sold (by itself)=Open, Sold (by itself)=Close. There are options tracking spreadsheets available, but nothing like what I'm trying to devise here. Being able to track everything by simply pasting the transaction from the broker into the spreadsheet would be huge help. Thanks.

Comment: @J. Feeble got it, you should edit your question to add this info in. Before you do though, how can a sold call always be both an opening and closing transaction? Based on the put scenario, my guess is you are always long as an opening transaction (so you meant to say "Bought/Call=Open")? Same question to Sold (by itself)

Comment: You're correct of course. That second "Sold/Call=Close" should have been "Bought/Call=Close". I'll edit the question and add this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j99DvsXoOvxCzSqLIa?e=Q3NyXu)/screenshots refer:

*(requires Office 365 compatible version Excel)*

**Main lookup**

[image: Sample lookup]

```
=LET(fn_1,MATCH("*"&$H$7:$H$12&"*",B4,0),fn_2,MATCH("*"&$I$7:$I$12&"*",B4,0),IFERROR(INDEX($J$7:$J$12,MATCH(1,IF($I$7:$I$12="",fn_1*ISNUMBER(fn_2),fn_1*fn_2),0)),))
```

**EDIT**:

Other Excel versions:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($J$7:$J$12,MATCH(1,IF($I$7:$I$12="",MATCH("*"&$H$7:$H$12&"*",B4,0)*ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&$I$7:$I$12&"*",B4,0)),MATCH("*"&$H$7:$H$12&"*",B4,0)*MATCH("*"&$I$7:$I$12&"*",B4,0)),0)),)
```

(all that falls away is the 'Let' formula, replacing fn_1 and fn_2 with respective functions in index formula within the let making first equation somewhat longer, but otherwise identical)

---

**Example applications**

Have provided 2 examples of how one might customize to insert numeric in one of the columns (the key part to this question is really how to do lookup in first instance, from thereon it's a matter of finetuning/taking appropriate action)...

Assuming calls/buys are "long" position and strike price go in first col (here, D), and puts/sales are "short" position with strike price going in 2nd col (here, E):

*Long - insert strike price col D*

[image: Long position - col D]

```
=IF(LET(fn_1,MATCH("*"&$H$7:$H$12&"*",B4,0),fn_2,MATCH("*"&$I$7:$I$12&"*",B4,0),IFERROR(INDEX($K$7:$K$12,MATCH(1,IF($I$7:$I$12="",fn_1*ISNUMBER(fn_2),fn_1*fn_2),0)),))=1,MID(SUBSTITUTE(B4," ",""),SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(B4," ",""))+1,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B4," ",""))),"")
```

**EDIT**

Other Excel versions:

```
=IF(IFERROR(INDEX($K$7:$K$12,MATCH(1,IF($I$7:$I$12="",MATCH("*"&$H$7:$H$12&"*",B4,0)*ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&$I$7:$I$12&"*",B4,0)),MATCH("*"&$H$7:$H$12&"*",B4,0)*MATCH("*"&$I$7:$I$12&"*",B4,0)),0)),)=1,MID(SUBSTITUTE(B4," ",""),SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(B4," ",""))+1,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B4," ",""))),"")
```

*Short - insert strike price col E*

[image: Short position - col E]

```
=IF(LET(fn_1,MATCH("*"&$H$7:$H$12&"*",B4,0),fn_2,MATCH("*"&$I$7:$I$12&"*",B4,0),IFERROR(INDEX($K$7:$K$12,MATCH(1,IF($I$7:$I$12="",fn_1*ISNUMBER(fn_2),fn_1*fn_2),0)),))=2,MID(SUBSTITUTE(B4," ",""),SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(B4," ",""))+1,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B4," ",""))),"")
```

**EDIT**

Other Excel versions:

*Follow same routine in previous Edits (remove Let, replace fn_1 & fn_2 with respective formulae...)*

---

*Note similarity in all 3 equations above: 2nd and 3rd contain 1st (effectively they just wrap a big old 'if' statement around 1st, use lookup_2 col (here, col K), and use mid/search to extract rate after the hashtag.
Assumes you don't have other hashtags in the sentence..
Customize as required.*

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer so thoroughly. I don't have Excel 365 yet, only 2019. But I will get that and try it.

Comment: @J.Feeble - see revision to accommodate other versions of Excel..